# React dnd Drop firing twice

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-dnd

I have a component Port which is both draggable and droppable.
I am using react-dnd. For backend I am using react-dnd-mouse-backend since I am working with svg and html5 backend does not support svg. I have a feeling that `react-dnd-mouse-backend` could be the root of the problem
The code for the component is as follows :-

Port.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import { itemTypes, portInnerRadius, portOuterRadius } from './constants';
import { DragSource, DropTarget } from 'react-dnd';

const portSource = {
    beginDrag: (props) => {
        const { id, pin, position } = props.port;
        console.log('Drag props ', id, pin, position );
        return {
            type: 'port',
            port: props.port
        };
    },

    endDrag: (props, monitor) => {
        if (!monitor.didDrop()) {
            console.log('Drop invalid');
            return;
        }
        const draggedPort = monitor.getItem().port;
        const droppedPort = monitor.getDropResult().port;
        console.log('dragged item ', draggedPort.id, draggedPort.pin);
        console.log('dropped item ', droppedPort.id, droppedPort.pin);
    }
};

const portTarget = {
    drop: (props) => {
        const { id, pin, position } = props.port;
        console.log('Drop props ', id, pin, position);
        return {
            type: 'port',
            port: props.port
        };
    }
};

function collectDrag(connect, monitor) {
    return {
        connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
        cursorDeltaOffset: monitor.getDifferenceFromInitialOffset()
    }
}

function collectDrop(connect, monitor) {
    return {
        connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
        isOver: monitor.isOver(),
        canDrop: monitor.canDrop()
    };
}

class Port extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        connectDragSource: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        isDragging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        cursorDeltaOffset: PropTypes.object
    }

    render() {
        const { connectDragSource, connectDropTarget, isDragging, cursorDeltaOffset, port } = this.props;
        const { position } = port;
        const { x, y } = position;

        let path = '';
        if ( isDragging && cursorDeltaOffset ) {
            path = `M${x},${y} l${cursorDeltaOffset.x},${cursorDeltaOffset.y}`;
        }

        return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(
            <g className={`g-connector-port`}>
                <g>
                    <circle className="circle-connector-pin circle-outer" cx={ position.x } cy={ position.y } r={ portOuterRadius } />
                    <circle className="circle-connector-pin circle-inner" cx={ position.x } cy={ position.y } r={ portInnerRadius } />
                </g>
                { isDragging && path &&
                    <path className="path-port-drag" d={ path } stroke="black"/>
                }
            </g>
        ));
    }
}


export default compose(
    DragSource(itemTypes.PORT, portSource, collectDrag),
    DropTarget(itemTypes.PORT, portTarget, collectDrop)
)(Port);
```

The problem is that when I try to drag from one port to another, sometimes it works fine. But some other times the drop gets fired twice.

https://gyazo.com/5956c9c75fcf9c3bf93e1b5c5281bcd7

As you can see above, the 1st time when I connect left box pin 1 to right box pin 1.
The log should be

```
drag props 1 1
drop props 2 1
```

instead, it is

```
drag props 1 1
drop props 2 1 
drop props 1 1
```

You can see the drop is happening twice, on the source and on the target.

The 2nd time when I connect left pin 2 to right pin 2, the log output is as expected.

Also in the following gif, notice how the isOver prop is randomly being set to true even though the cursor is not over it.
https://gyazo.com/9ca3652713ffab789e6d2fc0c3426cc7

I want to know why the drop is happening twice and why only on sometimes.

Comment: I had some exposure to using react dnd and another library that I think you should look into is React Konva. I have used this library for drag and drop feature for one of my applications.

Comment: I did a large project with react-dnd once. It's super buggy.

Both issues you mention (multiple drops and isOver randomly set to true) are related to DropTargetMonitor (https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drop-target-monitor.html). The issue seems to be the monitor method. It's not passing correct pointer offset info.

What do you get when you console log getDropResult()?

Comment: Actually, I do strongly feel that react-dnd-mouse-backend is the source of the issue, and there is almost no documentation there to help. It looks like HTML5 backend has now been merged into the main react-dnd repo. According to one of the issues there you can make it work with .svg by enclosing them in divs (https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/395). Maybe try getting rid of react-dnd-mouse-backend and trying that approach?

Comment: @223seneca Do you have any good suggestions for react-dnd subsitute ?
I'm evaluating React-Konva as Tim Han mentioned.

Comment: I suggest sticking with react-dnd. I was satisfied with the outcome once I tinkered with it enough to work. But you really should find a way not to use react-dnd-mouse-backend.

Comment: You need a `monitor.didDrop()` check in your `drop` handler.